# RoR: Type Error, false is not a symbol

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I am trying to validate what kind of role does the current logged in user has.
Role is a string column on the Users Model.

I am trying this:

```
<% if current_user.try(:role == 'admin') %>
  #Show something
<% end %>
```

And I get the following error:

```
TypeError in Merchants#index 
false is not a symbol
```

I have Devise as my authentication system, that is why I am using the current_user method

I used to have a boolean User.admin and it worked like this:

```
<% if current_user.try(:admin?) %>
  #Show something
<% end %>
```

I need to change to a string field since I will have several roles.

Comment: error is clear. `:role == 'admin'` gives *boolean*, but [`try`](http://apidock.com/rails/Object/try) method's first argument must be *symbol*.

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
<% if current_user.try(:role) == 'admin' %>
```

Comment: No error now but I still dont get the results I need. The current_user has a value of 'admin' on the user.role field and the if condition is not printing any value. I just hardcoded <%= current_user.role %> and I get "admin"